# Existing Web version (Cakephp) + API

Tags: cakephp

I have built a web application using Cakephp and have all the logic in the models.

I now need to expose an API so the mobile app can consume all these services.

Would it be acceptable to just expose the model methods as JSON services from that web layer?

is it not a good practice to have the API and the web in the same 'layer' and it would be better to have them separated?

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be acceptable to just expose the model methods as json
> services from that web layer?

Yes, if it's done right. By directly accessing the models you'll loose the auth which you very likely want to have.

An acceptable workaround for example could be to write an ApiController with a single method that dispatches the model method. This way you can control who accesses what action.

```
public function index($model, $method) {
    public function index() { 
        $this->set('data', ClassRegistry::init($model)->{$method});
    }
}
```

The code above is missing a view things like handling arguments, errors and [json/xml views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html), but I guess you get the idea. And don't forget auth, this will expose *all* public model methods.

You could implement this as well as a dispatcher filter to bypass controllers for even more performance. If you're using token auth you can check that there as well without problems. I recommend to use a [JWT](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-25), which avoids the need for an additional DB query, see [php-JWT](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt).

Yet another possibility would be to use routing prefixs like api_index(), to avoid redundant code you can do it like:

```
public function api_index() {
    $this->setAction('index');
}
```

See http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Controller.html#_setAction

> is it not a good practice to have the API and the web in the same
> 'layer' and it would be better to have them separated?

CakePHP is missing a "Service" layer between the controllers and models. You want to expose services, not models. Either you write that layer yourself or you simply re-use the models.

For any of the above solutions you can use the routing to create whatever API URL you want, for example /api/v1/:model/:method/. This way you could as well map a specific API URL to a specific model and method as well.

If you like you can contact me (see my profile), we have a good amount of experience with this "missing" layer and creating APIs.